# Laravel (v6.x) addSelect() always returns a null value for the subquery field

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have this Eloquent query:

```
$users = User::query()
            ->addSelect([
                'latest_login' => Login::select('login_time')
                ->where('logins.user_id', 'users.id')
                ->latest('login_time')
                ->take(1)
            ])
            ->orderBy('latest_login', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

The problem is that the `latest_login' field is always null.

However if I run the query in mysql the field is fully populated:

```
'SELECT `users`.*, (SELECT `login_time` FROM `logins` WHERE `user_id` = users.id AND `login_time` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `login_time` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `last_login` FROM `users` WHERE `logged_in` > 0 ORDER BY `last_login` DESC
```

I have also tried running the raw query in Laravel using DB::select() and that also returns null for the field.

Any ideas please?

Comment: If you have it as a model, why don'y you define a relationship and just make the query with that relation ship adding the where and order ?

Comment: https://eloquent-course.reinink.ca/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be wrong here but I think you have to use [`whereColumn`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereColumn) instead of `where`
to actually use the value of the column and not just a string with the column's name.

```
$users = User::query()
    ->addSelect([
        'latest_login' => Login::select('login_time')
            ->whereColumn('logins.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->latest('login_time')
            ->take(1)
    ])
    ->orderBy('latest_login', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. That's sorted it!

Comment: Glad it helped! Reinink‘s course is really good btw! Worth every penny.